# Intellij is not working with Address already in use for standalone java programs

Tags: java, intellij-idea

### I am trying to run standalone java program which does not connect to the server. I get the error as address already in use when I re-execute the code .When I restart and run the code  it works fine but after that when I immediately re-execute same or other program I am getting the below error.I did not configure the any host with the port. I am not sure from where Intellj is try to get the configuration

Abnormal build process termination:

```
"C:\Program Files\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/jna/amd64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/karth/Leetcode/leetcode -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/karth/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-7080171603453567732 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=IN -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2022.3 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/karth/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/karth/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/karth/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.5 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/karth/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/compile-server/leetcode_b0cc9da0/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\karth\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-658784108409213526-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/3rd-party-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49158 39d796f5-74f3-4929-a40b-c0909e3e304d C:/Users/karth/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:49158; reason: Address already in use: no further information: /127.0.0.1:49158
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address already in use: no further information: /127.0.0.1:49158
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:689)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exiting.
```

Comment: Can you post the source code Main class?

Comment: Can you provide more info about the project type, a Maven, or Gradle? Sample code is welcomed on GitHub or Google Drive.

Comment: import java.util.HashSet;import java.util.Set;
public class ReverseString {
    public static boolean isSubstringPresent(String s) {
        int i=0;int j=s.length()-1;Set<String> ss = new HashSet<>(); while(i<s.length()-1){
 String s1=s.charAt(i)+""+s.charAt(i+1);
  ss.add(s1);
   i++;
    }
   while (j>0){
  String s1=s.charAt(j)+""+s.charAt(j-1);
  if(ss.contains(s1)){
    return true;
  }j--;
  }return false;}
public static void main(String[] args) {String s="abcd";System.out.println(isSubstringPresent(s));}}